# Round up prices to end with 99p

Tags: sql, rounding

My table name is products and i am trying to update products_price so all prices have `99p` at the end.  Can you help?

Also this request is a bit simpler (i'm new to `SQL`!) I want to update all records as follows

anything in  `categories` where `parent_id` is >0 I need the script to update all records to **zero**.

Comment: "update products_price so all prices have 99p at the end" != "update all to zero" What are you asking? You're very unclear.

Comment: He's asking two different questions.

Comment: Which column or columns do you need to update to zero in the Categories table?  One comment indicated it should be the Parent ID column, but your updated question still does not make that clear.  We can't read minds reliably.

Answer (score 2):

#### Q1

So, you want all prices to be truncated and then add `0.99` currency units.  The function to truncate a value to 0 decimal places varies between DBMS; I'm assuming it is called TRUNC, but it might be called FLOOR or something else in your DBMS:

```
UPDATE Products
   SET Products_Price = TRUNC(Products_Price) + 0.99;
```

You don't need a WHERE clause here.  I'm assuming there are no negative prices; if that's a possibility, then you need to be a little cleverer with your assignment (maybe a CASE expression; maybe you have a function SIGN, SIGN, SIGNUM available).

Note that I'm assuming that the `p` referenced is pence, as in 'pounds (Sterling) and pence'.  If the price was between £0.00 and £0.99, the result will be £0.99; if the price was between £1.00 and £1.99, the result will be £1.99; etc. The TRUNC or FLOOR will remove any fractional part from the price, and the addition of 0.99 then means that the result is of the form £*x*.99 for (non-negative) integer values of *x*.

#### Q2

Making some assumptions about what you meant:

```
UPDATE Categories
   SET Anything = 0
 WHERE Anything > 0
   AND Parent_ID > 0;
```

If you meant that you want to update the products table in some way, then you need to be a lot more precise in your question.

---

#### Q2 revisited

From a comment:

> I want to update all `parent_id` values in my `categories` table to zero where `parent_id > 0`.

Presumably, there must be some `parent_id` values which are null or negative, so you need:

```
UPDATE Categories
   SET Parent_ID = 0
 WHERE Parent_ID > 0
```

If there are no nulls and no negatives, then you can run an even simpler update:

```
UPDATE Categories
   SET Parent_ID = 0
```

It will set to zero those rows which already have a parent ID of zero as well as those that do not.  This might hit the logs a bit harder than the more selective update (as in, there will be more changes to record in the logical log or equivalent for your DBMS), but unless there are vast numbers of records and most of them already have a zero parent ID and the DBMS does not recognize when a record does not change and writes log records for unchanged rows, then you're unlikely to notice the difference

Comment: TRUNC and FLOOR do different things for negative numbers. TRUNC rounds towards 0, FLOOR towards negative infinity. But negative numbers generally don't make sense for prices.

Comment: will your answer to question 1 set all prices to 99p?

Comment: If the price was between £0.00 and £0.99, the result will be £0.99; if the price was between £1.00 and £1.99, the result will be £1.99; etc.  The TRUNC or FLOOR will remove any fractional part from the price, and the addition of 0.99 then means that the result is of the form £_x_.99 for (non-negative) integer values of _x_.  If you simply want everything to be £0.99, then you don't need the TRUNC or FLOOR or any other function, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Set price to have 99p at end:

```
update products_price set price = floor(price)+0.99;
```

Set parent_id to 0:

```
update categories set parent_id = 0 where parent_id > 0;
```

Comment: My reading of the question for part 1 has the table name as `Products`; the column is `Products_price`.  The interpretation of part 2 is very, very open to discussion.

Comment: products_price sounds more like the name of a table relating products to prices. I don't think it's a big deal, what he needs is the general structure of the SQL.

Comment: If price is 3.87, floor(price) is 3.00, and floor(price)+0.99 is 3.99.

Comment: You're still not being clear in your second question. What do you mean by "update everything"? There's no built-in way to update all columns in a table, you have to say which columns you want to update.

Comment: Will Q1 suggestion above not set all prices to 99p ? An example of what I need is say a product is priced at £3.87 , well I want to update all such records in the 'products' table to end in .99 Field name of price = 'products_price'                In reply to Q2 above i want to update all 'parent_id''s in my'categories' table to zero where 'parent_id' >0 Thanks all

Comment: @WingMan: so, for the £3.87 data, you want the result to be £3.99, do you not?  That is what Barmar's statement will provide.  If you mean something else, you need to say so — it would have been helpful if you'd been explicit in your previous comment.

Comment: yes update products set products_price = floor(products_price) +0.99; worked just fine as did jonathans script for Q2  thank you all :)